# Load image after json respond

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

How can I load an image after successful json respond?

**jQuery**

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Upload", "Camera")', {
  type: 'data',
  image: canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
}, function (result) {
  if(result.success) {
    alert('The image was successfully sent to the server for processing');

    var $image = $("<img src='~/temp/" + @ViewData["CaputredImage"] + "'/>");
    $image.live("load", function () {
      $("#imageContainer").append(this);
    });

  }
});
```

**Image container**

```
<div id="imageContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably include the path to the newly-submitted image in the JSON sent back from the server, and then:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Upload", "Camera")', {
  type: 'data',
  image: canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
}, function (result) {
  if(result.success) {
    alert('The image was successfully sent to the server for processing');

    // *** Change is on next line ***
    var $image = $("<img src='" + result.imagePath + "'/>");
    // *** Another change on the next line ***
    $image.on("load", function () {
      $("#imageContainer").append(this);
    });

  }
});
```

Also note I changed the `live` call to `on`. That wasn't the correctly way to use `live` in the first place, and secondly it's been deprecated for a while and has now actually been removed.

Separately, you have a race condition there (although in this case, one that's very unlikely to actually cause you a problem): You aren't hooking the `load` event of the image until *after* you've specified its `src`. Although JavaScript on browsers is single-threaded (unless you use web workers), the *browser* is *not*. If it already has the image in cache (again, unlikely in this case), it can fire the `load` event before you hook it — and seeing no handlers attached to the event, it doesn't queue them to run when the JavaScript is next idle.

Also (at the other extreme), you're waiting to add the image to the document until after it's loaded; I'm not 100% certain all browsers will load the image if it's not in any document.

So for what it's worth:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Upload", "Camera")', {
  type: 'data',
  image: canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
}, function (result) {
  if(result.success) {
    alert('The image was successfully sent to the server for processing');

    // *** Changes start here ***
    var $image = $("<img>");
    $image.css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: -10000,
        top: 0
    });
    $image.attr("src", image.imagePath);
    $image.appendTo(document.body);
    $image.on("load", function () {
      $image.remove();
      $("#imageContainer").append("<img src='" + result.imagePath + "'>");
    });
    // *** End of changes ***
  }
});
```

That creates an `img` element off-page but in the document, hooks image load, sets the `src`, and on load drops that `img` element in favor of a newly-created one that doesn't have the CSS applied to it. (You can chain those calls together, kept them separated for clarity.)

Comment: not working! the thing is I don't think `load` would work here after json respond

Comment: @JackManson: Sure it will. The one has nothing to do with the other. There must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
   $("#imageContainer").append(img);
}); 
img.src ='~/temp/' + @ViewData["CaputredImage"] ;
```